# How can I create and poll tags from Carbon?

Tags: time-series, metrics, graphite, graphite-carbon

Carbon 1.1.x [added the feature for tagging series](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tags.html#graphite-tag-support). I've attempted to add a tag to a series via the below:

`curl -vv -X POST "http://10.x.x.x:8080/tags/tagSeries" --data-urlencode 'path=qa-dev.stats.UpdateStats.responses.OK.calls.mean_rate;env=qa-dev'`

Then if I do: `curl -vv "http://10.x.x.x:8080/tags/findSeries?pretty=1&expr=env=qa-dev"`, I get what I'd expect as output:

```
[
  "qa-dev.stats.UpdateStats.responses.OK.calls.mean_rate;env=qa-dev"
* Connection #0 to host 10.19.118.17 left intact
]
```

However, if I try to poll this series with an `aliasByTags` via my renderer, the tags aren't present:

`http://internal.graphite.abc.com/render/?target=aliasByTags(qa-dev.stats.UpdateStats.responses.OK.calls.mean_rate,%20%27env%27)&from=-6h&until=now&format=json&maxDataPoints=1440`

The above will pull data points, but the only tags that are represented at the end of the returned data is the name:

`"tags": {"name": "qa-dev.stats.UpdateStats.responses.OK.calls.mean_rate"}`.

I'd expected to see `env=qa-dev` in the tags list, but it's not.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The tag api is used by carbon to add tagged series to the internal database in graphite-web, it is not intended to add tags to existing un-tagged series.

To use tagged series you need to update your collector/producer to generate tagged series.

The idea is that you shouldn't need to embed the env in the series name if you're using tags, so your series would be something like `stats.UpdateStats.responses.OK.calls.mean_rate;env=qa-dev`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to tag series with sample code. I am new to graphite and I can seem to get a grasp of tagging. You can view how I solved my problem with a walk-around solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52897070/grahite-carbon-collectd-statsd-tagged-series-in-python-program/53011458#53011458)