# Grahite, Carbon, CollectD, StatsD - Tagged Series in Python Program

Tags: python, resources, metrics, graphite, graphite-carbon

I am trying to run some some python/other language modules modules/workflows/workloads and collect their CPU, Mem, I/O etc resource usage with Grahite, Carbon, CollectD, StatsD. I have read the documentation (see:[here](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tags.html)) about creating tagged series but what I can't seem to find  how to tag specific moudles. For example, I have two modules

First Module

```
def firstModule:
    # Initialize a list
    primes = []

    for possiblePrime in range(2, 21):
       # Assume number is prime until shown it is not. 

       isPrime = True

       for num in range(2, possiblePrime):
          if possiblePrime % num == 0:
          isPrime = False

    if isPrime:
        primes.append(possiblePrime)
```

Second Module

```
def secondModule:
    # Initialize a list

    primes = []

    for possiblePrime in range(2, 21):

        # Assume number is prime until shown it is not. 

        isPrime = True

        for num in range(2, possiblePrime):
            if possiblePrime % num == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break

    if isPrime:
        primes.append(possiblePrime)
```

Here I want to call the two modules and then tag resource usage metrics so that I can send it to the whisper database as shown in code below: How do I achieve that?

```
firstModule() # assign some tag say A
secondModule() # assign some tag say B
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I ended up not using a tagged series, I have solved the problem above by writing a bash script and using the [render api](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html) in graphite. Here is the walk around solution:

```
    #!/bin/bash   

    #Remove previous records. Be careful not to remove useful files!
    rm cpu.json, mem.json

    #clear variables for storing time 
    unset start
    unset finish

    #log start time of process using absolute time, if using relative time check doc at https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html for rules
    start=$(date '+%H:%M_%Y%m%d')

    #call first module
    firstModule()

    #sleep 1 minute or more because you will get an error that start time and end time are equal
    sleep 100

    #call second module
    secondModule()

    #log finish date using absolute time, if using relative time check  doc at https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/render_api.html) for rules
    finish=$(date '+%H:%M_%Y%m%d')

    #collect data using curl here cpu usage and memusage, adjust to fit your setup and Voila!
    curl "http://host/render?target=carbon.agents.*.cpuUsage&width=500&height=300&from={$start}&until={$finish}&format=json" > cpu.json
    sudo curl "http://host/render?target=collectdlocalhost.memory.memory-used&width=500&height=300&from={$start}&until={$finish}&format=json" > mem.json
```